# how to create angular div in html5 css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help in creating diagonal div as shown in the picture. i have diagonal design with triangles at top right and bottom left with using absolute positioning and z-index. And this div will be the main div having content in it. I need to make a div similar to the picture. 
i tried using transform skew property but that does not help.
Any help will be appreciable. 
The div will have something like this

```
<div class="tr-corner"><img src="tr.png"></div>
<div class="main">
<div class="content">
Blah blah blah
</div>
</div>
<div class="bl-corner"><img src="bl.png"></div>
```

CSS

```
.tr-corner{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
z-index: 1;
}
.bl-corner{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index: 3;
}
```

Now i need to create the div with id "main" to be diagonal as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Example on Skew. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`skew()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew) to achieve that

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    transform: skew(20deg,0);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RW53m/)

---

Make sure you add proprietary properties as well, so that old browser versions don't fail to render.

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg,0);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg,0);
    transform: skew(20deg,0);
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/RW53m/1/) *(Added proprietary properties.. especially for chrome users)*

---

[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) is pretty sweet..

[image]

<sup>Credits : [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)</sup>

Comment: thanks for the help, the site will be responsive website with 100% width, will this work on smaller resolutions properly. As the standard screen resolution will be 1920X1080 and the width of the div should adjust itself on smaller desktop resolutions like 1600X1200 and 1280X720.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css3's skew:

```
div {
  -ms-transform: skew(30deg,20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skew(30deg,20deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: skew(30deg,20deg);
   }
```

dont forget to fill in the div with colors :)